# CSS - nth-child() example

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given the example below, each row needs to have three text columns, i.e. three sentences, where the middle ones also need to have a `background-color`. Is it possible to do that with the `nth-child()` *selector*?

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

p:nth-child(2n+0) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Hello @Bst_coder

Try this

   p:nth-child(3n+2) {
        background: red;
        }

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
p:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `flex` to `wrap` and to `p` use `p:nth-child(3n+2)`

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
flex: 1 0 33%;
}

   p:nth-child(3n+2){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it can be done - i would not do it this way. But in the interest of getting the styling that you want - if the number and alignment is always as you have it here then you can do it as follows.

This will give the rows of p elements and will give a background color on the middle p element in each row - thereby creating a "column" effect. but you really should use a better HTML structure.

```css
p {
display:inline-block;
width:30%;
}

p:nth-child(2), 
p:nth-child(5), 
p:nth-child(8) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: You should also give an example of the better HTML structure that you hint at.